# How to set a table cell 2 colors?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How to create `<td>` with 2 colors?

This is my code :

```
<table cellspacing=0>
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor=green><img src='pic/s.gif' width=8 height=5></td>
    <td bgcolor=#AAAAAA><img src='pic/s.gif' width=72 height=5></td>
    <td style="color: green;">10%</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

but I want use **one** `td` and write 10% on `td` with `z-index=1` but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are aiming to achieve with these 'two colours'. Can you give us a quick drawing to show what you mean?

Comment: @user3172276 Kindly explain the question, it is unclear

Comment: can't understand clearly. But your code look like this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T7CNL/2/  . you're missing double quotes and back slashes. first change it properly...

Comment: I think he wants the background color to be green for the left 10% of the cell, `#AAAAAA` for the right 90%. Like a gradient, except it just changes suddenly.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/T7CNL/3/ ????

Comment: OK these are right but I should use just **one** `td`

Answer (score 3):

Interesting concept, but do you really need a table layout?

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/75H74/1/) with a slightly different approach.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
            <div class='celldiv'>20%
                <div class='variablediv'></div>
            </div>
        </td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.celldiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.variablediv {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

And you can dynamically change the width of the blue and the number with jQuery.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are expecting the result like this...

[**DEMO JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T7CNL/4/)

**HTML**

```
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td class="red"></td>
           <td class="green"><span class="ten">10%</span></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.red
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
}
.green
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 90px;
    height: 5px;
}
.ten
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: @Maysam : like this http://jsfiddle.net/T7CNL/6/ . here i'm using one td and multiple span...??

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way you could do this would to be create an image in something like photoshop and chose the two colours that you want to use and space them out as you want. Then do something like this with the code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url('test/test.jpg');background-size:cover;">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                     <td width="10%">10%</td>
                     <td width="90%">90%</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its is dynamic and values changes

Comment: If you are aiming for it to be dynamic then my above example will work - You will have to make sure that the background-size is set to cover though. This then means it will shrink and grow with the table

Answer (score 0):

you have many possibilities cross browser and not : demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zDAof

- inset shadow,
- linear-gradient -
- background-image
- a mixed or else ?

```
table {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
td {
  background:red;
  padding-left:11%;
}
tr:first-child td {
  box-shadow:inset  10vw 0  0  green
}
tr:nth-child(2) td {
  background:linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    green 0,
    green 10%,
    transparent 10%,
    transparent 100%
  ) red;
}tr:nth-child(3) td {
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/2000x1/ff0000/ff0000) repeat-y right green;
  background-size:90%;
}
tr:last-child td {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,
    green,
    green 10%,
    red 10%,
    red);
}
```

html for demo :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> inset shadow
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Linear- gradient + bg color
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      background-image repeat-y
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      linear-gradient
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```